Multi statements SQL and C++
I'm using MSCV2019(x86), C++ 20, MariaDB 11.3, Windows 10(x64). My goal is to insert values into different tables in MariaDB server. Here's the code I'm struggling with:
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <format>
#include "mysql/mysql.h"

const char* user = "root";
const char* passwd = "password";
const char* host = "127.0.0.1";
const char* db; // = "data";
int   port = 3306;
MYSQL* connection = NULL, conn;


int main()
{
    mysql_init(&conn);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&conn, host, user, passwd, NULL, port, NULL, CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS);     

    auto resDB = mysql_select_db(&conn, "2024_04");  

    int odr1 = 0;
    int odr2 = 1;
    std::string str_concat = "";

    while (true) {
        std::string str_queryInsert1 = std::format("INSERT INTO tb (odr1, odr2) values( {}, {})", odr1, odr1);
        std::string str_queryInsert2 = std::format("INSERT INTO tb (odr1, odr2) values( {}, {})", odr2, odr2);

        str_concat.append(str_queryInsert1);
        str_concat.append(";");
        str_concat.append(str_queryInsert2);
        str_concat.append(";");

        odr1 += 1;
        odr2 += 1;

        if ((odr1 % 4) == 0) {    
            auto res = mysql_query(&conn, str_concat.c_str());
            //auto res = mysql_query(&conn, str_queryInsert1.c_str());
            Sleep(1000);
            str_concat = "";

            std::cout << "SENT";
        }
    } 
}
 

It works well when it sends one query at a time(mysql_query(&conn, str_queryInsert1.c_str())), but if it sends multiple insert queries as one statement(mysql_query(&conn, str_concat.c_str())), the server doesn't receive it after the first one or two times. Why does it not keep working?


never ignore response of systems you are using. I bet res can tell you what went wrong

The documentation is very adamant about processing the results of your queries using mysql_store_result and mysql_next_result. You are not doing that.

The lack of seperation of result/error condition makes multistatement as not something that should be used.

This code is fully vulnerable to SQL injection. Never use string formatting, concatenation or interpolation to create SQL queries. It's not just unsafe, it's also slow and vulnerable to formatting errors. Think what would happen if odr1 contained 1,1); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; or a date

I'm sorry for the poor quality of the code! I just wanted to figure the problem out and make it work first.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I actually checked the return values. When it works, it returns 0, when it doesn't work, it returns -1 and mysql_error returns 67. I couldn't find anything about them on the internet though. (OpenAI said it has to do with too many connections, but I'm not sure if it does)

You're using C++ so why not use the C++ classes instead ? In the Github repo I see both C and C++ have an addBatch function to batch multiple statements together. If you use C++, all you have to do is call addBatch on the Statement object

dont expect an AI to produce anything meaningful when you cannot find the same information online.

OpenAI said that's a statistical text generator producing output based on your prompt. Every generated word is based on the statistics of your question and the previous words in the output. In other words, pretty random unless you're very specific, which only happens if you actually read the docs. And tell OpenAI itself to read the docs and assume it's a C++ developer etc etc.

@Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you for the recommendation. I'll try using it. I hope it works fine with x86 working environments.

@maynull given that 90% of computers are x86, yes it will. That's what it was tested on. Even if you mean 64-bit vs 32-bit, there were no affordable 64-bit CPUs when C++03 was released and I'd even say that C++11 mostly run on 32-bit machines.

Besides, you're running on a 64-bit OS, with a compiler that generates both 32 and 64-bit programs for decades

@Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you for the confirmation! 64-bit x86 download option somehow made me unsure ;) It's because I have to use 32bit modules(very old) to receive realtime data. I've been using Python and hdf5 so far, but it seems fate has drawn C++ and me together!

why do you want to use multi statements?  do them one at a time, if they are inserts to different tables.  if the same table, do insert into tb (col1, col2) values (val1, val2),(val3,val4)

This code is vulnerable to SQL injections only if some inputs of the request are user provided, which is not the case here.

I second the comment from ysth. There is no benefit to using multi-query. Just execute one statement at a time. Also multi-query is incompatible with using prepared statements.
